# Why should i use/not-use a nullable field Laravel - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `Address table` in my mySQL database with some fields.

On my form i ask a user to input values for these fields. But the `street field is not required` . So when my form gets submitted my Column Street is just empty in my database. This works fine and gives no errors without setting the column to accept NULL .

So my **question** is :

What is the benefit of setting the Street column to nullable?

Example migration (Laravel) without nullable:

```
$table->string('street');
```

Example Migration with nullable

```
$table->string('street')->nullable();
```

Both work fine .

Comment: In your case, it probably doesn't really matter. In some other application, an empty string may not be the same thing as the absence of a string, so null serves a purpose there. I generally make fields that could be left out nullable as a best practice, but it's not something you have to do.

Comment: can you give an example where it will matter?

Comment: Unless you know you need the difference, it is unlikely to matter. :)

Comment: Ok, so basically the answer  is to always use nullable because it will always work as intended? You can post that as an answer so i will accept it :)

Comment: I'll await some other answer as well, maybe somebody has better input. I don't think it's good enough as an answer on its own. But thank you. :)

Comment: In this case I don't think it matters but nullable can be useful for foreign key columns.  Let's say you have a `user_id` foreign key on your `address` table and for some reason you have an address you need to store which doesn't belong to a `user`, you'd be able to set that `user_id` column to null and it should still work without violating the foreign key constraints where an empty space would.

Comment: @user3158900 That is actually the answer i was looking for! Because i do have foreign key constraints in this case. Can you post that as an answer because that is really useful information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a good practice to use explicit instead of implicit where it's possible. So I'd go with `nullable` and `is_null()` checking for null.

With this approach you get less bugs, more readable code etc.